# Swift casting UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> in C callback

Tags: ios, c, swift, casting

Trying to interface with iOS AudioQueues using swift, and hitting a roadblock when attempting to pass an object defining my state.

My state object is a custom struct defined as:

```
struct UserData {
var active: Bool = false
var audioFileId: AudioFileID = nil
}
```

My swift audio input callback:

```
        let myCallback : @convention(c) (UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, AudioQueueRef, AudioQueueBufferRef, UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>, UInt32, UnsafePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>) -> Void = {
        (inUserData, inAQ, inBuffer, inStartTime, inNumberPacketDescriptions, inPacketDescs) -> Void in
      ...
    }
```

Lastly, initializing the audio queue:

```
        AudioQueueNewInput(&audioStreamBasicDescription, myCallback, &userData, nil, nil, 0, &inputQueue)
```

Where I'm stuck is figuring out how to cast `inUserData: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>` to my UserData struct

Or, of course, any better way of handling this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either

```
let userData: UserData = UnsafePointer(inUserData).memory
```

or

```
let userData = UnsafePointer<UserData>(inUserData).memory
```

both are equivalent. See also the [UnsafeMutablePointer Structure Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_UnsafeMutablePointer_Structure/index.html).

To return some modified data you can use

```
let userDataReference = UnsafeMutablePointer<UserData>(inUserData)
var userData = userDataReference.memory
userData.… = … /* modifiy local copy */
userDataReference.memory = userData
```

You could also modify `userDataReference.memory` directly, but I would advise against it.

Comment: sorry to add on..is it possible to modify the property of the struct in my callback? Given an additional property var packetsProcessed: Int64 = 0, and being able to set it in the callback